# ServletContext instance not available in AuthenticationProvider after implementing ServletConextAware

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a

1. `CustomAuthenticationProvider` by implementing `AuthenticationProvider`
2. `CustomUserDetailsService` by implementing `UserDetailsService`

The problem

I'm have implemented `ServletContextAware` in the both the implementation I'm able to get the `ServletContextAware` only in `CustomUserDetailsService` and not in `CustomAuthenticationProvider`.

What is the reason behind it?

In order to get the `ServletContext` in `CustomUserDetailsService`, what is the best way to do it?

Examples are given below.

**Example of CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
public CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, ServletContextAware{

      private ServletContext servletContext;

       @override
       public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
                     throws AuthenticationException{

            System.out.println("Context Path :: "+servletContext);  // Here the reference is NULL
       } 

       @Override 
       void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext){
          this.servletContext = servletContext;
       }  
}
```

**Example of CustomUserDetailsService**

```
public CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService, ServletContextAware{

        private ServletContext servletContext;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadByUserName(final String login){

            System.out.println("Context Path :: "+servletContext);  // Here the reference is NOT NULL
        }


       @Override 
       void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext){
          this.servletContext = servletContext;
       }  


}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


  @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Post your configuration, also the methods should be public not package protected.

Comment: The methods are public only, they are overridden methods from the Interface. Here the configuration are auto. But unable to understand why ServletContextAware is not available in AuthenticationProvider but really I need the ServletContext in this Implementation.

Comment: They aren't public in your class, they are package protected at least the code you show here. What do you mean with auto as there aren't any annotations on your class. So again please add the configuration of those 2 classes.

Comment: @Deinum Sorry I'm unable to get your point, since both the classes are in the same package, you can see both the implementation. Now I have provided the spring security configuration for your kind reference.

Comment: The fact that they are in the same package doesn't make a difference... What I want to know is HOW are those classes instantiated. If this is all the source code, then HOW are you creating an instance of those custom classes. That is what I want to know. Instead of sample code show some actual or representing code because I doubt that this code is fully representing what you have locally.